# Making card configurations in Sagemath

Tags: sage

I'm following [SageMath's tutorial on Combinatorics](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/tutorial.html#sage-combinat-tutorial) and one of the exercizes is to calculate the set of Four of a Kind hands (in card games a hand containing four cards of the same value is called a four of a kind and a Hand is a subset of 5 cards). Each card has a Value and a Suit.

I want to generate the hand in a structured way like {(1,"Hearts"), (1,"Spades"), (1,"Hearts"), (1,"Hearts"), (5,"Clubs") )}, so my idea was to create all the cards first and then join them in a set, like so:

```
Suits = Set(["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"])
Values = Set([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
              "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"])
Cards = cartesian_product([Values, Suits])

pick = Subsets(Values,1)
card1 = Set([pick, Subsets(Suits,1)])
card2 = Set([pick, Subsets(Suits,1)])
card3 = Set([pick, Subsets(Suits,1)])
card4 = Set([pick, Subsets(Suits,1)])
card5 = Subsets(Cards,1)

FourOfaKind = Set( {card1,card2,card3,card4,card5})

FourOfaKind.cardinality()
```

However the cardinality of FourOfaKind (supposedly the set of Four of a Kinds) is 2, which is clearly wrong.

**Edit:** I managed to do what I wanted but now I realized that I  don't want reposition in the choice of Suits. Here's the new code:

```
pick = Values.random_element()

card1 = Subsets(cartesian_product([Set([pick]), Suits]),1)
card2 = Subsets(cartesian_product([Set([pick]), Suits]),1)
card3 = Subsets(cartesian_product([Set([pick]), Suits]),1)
card4 = Subsets(cartesian_product([Set([pick]), Suits]),1)
card5 = Subsets(Cards,1)

FourOfaKind = cartesian_product([card1,card2,card3,card4,card5])

FourOfaKind.cardinality()

FourOfaKind.random_element()
```

My problem now is how can i tell Sage Math that I don't want keep the choice of the previous card? If I instantiate a Suit with Suit.random_element() each time I fix a card, then that won't be counted as part of the construction of the Suit/{whatever suit is instantiated} for the following cards, which puts me in quite a pickle! I'm sure there's some method to do this but I've been at hours for this and the Sage documentation is huge!

Any help is very valid!

Thank you!

Comment: Asked and answered at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/69313/making-card-configurations-in-sagemath/